# Customize the predefined request-type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I'm stuck in a problem. I'm using react-admin for the admin panel.
Now, when editing a contact the API is called with resource type `GET_ONE`.

I want to add the data to the reducer so that my component can use that data. Currently, the API is getting called and the fields are getting the value.

I just want to add the data to the reducer or want to call the API on the component `componentDidMount` method.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You can dispatch the action from the component by using bindActionCreators.

Comment: @AlokMali I cannot do that. The component is calling the API itself. And in the action, I'm not getting the dispatch. So, I cannot add it to the reducer.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You will get dispatch after use of bindActionCreators

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dispatch method in your component like that...

**Component**

```
/** Import */
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

/** methods */
selectProduct = index => {
   this.props.dispatch({ type: "selectedProduct", payload: index });
};

onDeleteProduct = index => {
   this.props.onDeleteProduct(index);
};

/** actions */
const mapActionsToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    dispatch,
    ...bindActionCreators({ onDeleteProduct: deleteProduct }, dispatch)
  };
};
```